# Diferencia entre proyectos PCL y .NET Standard visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, xamarin

Buen dia, quiero saber cual es la diferencia entre proyectos PCL y .NET Standard tengo visual studio community 2017 y cuando creo un proyecto xamarin forms me sale solo la opcion de crearlo con .NET Standard y he visto tutoriales que les sale es PCL, alguien me puede explicar que tengo que hacer o si son lo mismo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PCL segun Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/cross-platform/cross-platform-development-with-the-portable-class-library):

> Las bibliotecas de Clases Portátiles pueden ayudarlo a reducir el
>   tiempo y los costos de desarrollar y probar el código. Utilice este
>   tipo de proyecto para escribir y construir ensamblajes de .NET
>   Framework portátiles, y luego haga referencia a esos ensamblajes desde
>   aplicaciones que apuntan a múltiples plataformas como Windows y
>   Windows Phone.

En otras palabras, los proyectos tipo **P**ortable **C**lass **L**ibrary son funcionales cuando quieres que tu librería este disponible para distintas plataformas como windows phone y a la vez para Xbox. Las plataformas soportas son las siguientes:
[image: Plataformas soportadas]

Mientras que las Standard son las que solo son soportadas por windows y .net framework. Esto quiere decir que no podras utilizar en un proyecto windows phone o Xbox.